# Typescript: importing module from test

Tags: typescript

Let's say, I have a project that implements a module "foo".

Within some test I'd like to import "foo" itself (without using a relative import).

```
import * as foo from "foo";
```

However, it looks like the module resolver doesn't figure out that the current project is indeed "foo", but fails.

Comment: If you have separate `tsconfig.json` file for tests, you can map `foo` to your project top-level directory using [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)

Comment: And how does then node find the import?

Comment: Well, you can try to set [NODE_PATH](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) environment variable to the parent directory of your `foo` project  (assuming it's in directory named `foo`). But I think it's not really worth the trouble to make `import from "foo"` work when "foo" is not installed under `node_modules` yet.